# Как обнулить переменную?

Tags: c#

У меня возникла проблема, нужно обнулить переменную когда она превысит длину массива.

к примеру

```
 int i=0;    
 do {
   // нужно, чтобы шло перечисление до конца массива, но когда i=content.Length 
   //  i стало равно 0, перечисление продолжилось с начала массива и до его конца
    // и так пока i = content.Lentgh  
    ICr nextGen = content [i];
    i++;
 }
 while(content.Count !=0);
```

Comment: Вам принципиально использовать цикл do while?

Comment: внутри do есть еще код, и это есть оптимальный вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для перебора элементов массива удобнее всего пользоваться циклом `for`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
{
    ICr nextGen = content[i];
    ...
}
```

Если вы не собираетесь модифицировать массив, то разумно пользоваться циклом `foreach`:

```
foreach (ICr nextGen in content)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Решение с `do-while`. Учтите, что если не изменять количество элементов массива в этом цикле, то цикл будет бесконечным (т.к `content.Count != 0` будет всегда `true`).

```
int i = 0;    
do {
    if (i == content.Length)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    ICr nextGen = content[i];

    i++;
} while(content.Count != 0);
```

Comment: это я понимаю, но когда i = c.Length , цикл закончится., а мне нужно , чтоб он заново начал проходиться по массиву до его конца

Comment: @FlyFox обновил. Может разместите больше инфы по проблеме, авось подскажем решение получше...

Comment: Спасибо, последнее помогло )

Comment: Чем foreach лучше, чем for для обхода в случае, если не нужно модифицировать масси?